# remove value counts from pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I had the code pattern which provides the output in pandas.series type.From that i need to remove the value counts column without changing the pattern of table.

the code i have tried is,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b'],'C':['1','2'],
               'B':[[['A1', 'A2']],[['A1', 'A2', 'A3']]]})

df = df['B'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0])).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('B').join(df[['A','C']], how='left')
print(df.groupby(['A', 'C']).value_counts().sort_index())
```

the output i got is

```
A  C  B 
a  1  A1    1
      A2    1
b  2  A1    1
      A2    1
      A3    1
dtype: int64
```

the expected result is

```
A  C  B 
a  1  A1    
      A2    
b  2  A1    
      A2    
      A3
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you calculating the `value_counts` when you do not want them? `df.set_index(['A', 'C'])['B']`

Comment: Actually i don't need the value counts, i need the output pattern. as i mentioned above.. The output pattern which i excepted is obtained in groupby.valuecounts().. Unfortunately i don't know how to remove that. The data duplication is happening in column C.

Comment: From your desired output dataframe, if you are looking for columns A, C to be empty for column B = A2, then you are modifying the dataframe entirely. You can't expect when you query A=a & C=1 to return A1, A2, it will return only A1. So are you sure about that? I don't think that's what you want. So df.set_index(['A', 'C']['B] is what you want presumably.

Comment: Do you want that expected result to be a dataframe with three columns?

Comment: Otherwise the inner most level of the index must be on each row.  Therefore, in your expected output A and C can't be in the index where B is a column.

Comment: Yeah got it @SomeDude

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need [DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). However you'll also need to remove a level of nesting from your `"B"` column as well (since each value has a nested list). You can do the following:

```py
out = (
    # select 0th element from each list to reduce nesting
    df.assign(B=lambda df_: df['B'].str[0]) 
    # apply DataFrame transformation
    .explode('B')
)

# mask away duplicate values in A & C
to_mask = ['A', 'C']
out.loc[:, to_mask] = (
    out.loc[:, to_mask].mask(lambda df_: df_.apply(pd.Series.duplicated), '')
)

print(out)
   A  C   B
0  a  1  A1
0        A2
1  b  2  A1
1        A2
1        A3
```

Setting the index leads to this output:

```py
print(out.set_index(['A', 'C']))
      B
A C    
a 1  A1
     A2
b 2  A1
     A2
     A3
```

Comment: Actually i need avoid data duplication in column C

Comment: What value are you expecting in the second row of 'C'? e.g. if C were a list and you don't want it to be `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]` what do you want it to be?

Comment: It should be empty without any nan values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to use `set_index()`?

```
df.set_index(['A', 'C'])
```

[image]

Comment: actually i need to avoid the data duplication of C column also in dataframe @Zander. I need the output in above format